# PHP validation function

Tags: php, validation

What is better to return error code or add error code in error array

```
 private function playerIdValidation()
{
    if(!isset($this->betslip["player_id"]) || !is_int($this->betslip["player_id"]))
    {
        $this->success = false;
        array_push($this->betslip["errors"], 1);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

It's better to push element to array in function level or return error code and push into array in higher level?

Comment: Or throw an exception? It depends.

Comment: It's really depending what you are looking for. With a value return you can always call the function and see if everything is right what you are looking for `exp. if(playerIdValidation($element) != 1)`. If you are storing all your errors in arrays, then you should go for that. But nethertheless you will need to check the value on the array so you can work on. But it's the best if you are building your site for different languages.